# Kafka Consumer from python NoBrokersAvailable

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am using docker to run a kafka producer with the command

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --topic USER_CREATED_TOPIC --broker-list xxx.xx.x.x:9092`
```

where the x are numbers from the assigned broker ip.

My `server.properties` file contains

```
advertised.port=9092
advertised.host.name=xxx.xx.x.x.
listeners=PLAINTEXT://xxx.xx.x.x:9092 line
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://xxx.xx.x.x:9092
```

Whenever i am starting a consumer from the docker container with the command

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic USER_CREATED_TOPIC --from-beginning --bootstrap-server xxx.xx.x.x:9092
```

and write something in my producer console i get the result in the consumer.(no error here)

However, when i try to connect via python script using:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
  consumer = 
  kafkaConsumer("USER_CREATED_TOPIC",bootstrap_servers= 
  ['xxx.xx.x.x:9092'])
for msg in consumer:
     print (msg)
```

I am getting an `NoBrokersAvailable` error.

I read couple of threads on stackoverflow ( listed the added items on the `server.properties` based on those answers) but i am still unable to connect to the kafka producer via python.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted Kafka brokers after modifying the `server.properties` file?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yes i did

Comment: Although even if i use docker commit the changes doesnt seem to apply.

Answer (score 0):

The only syntaxical issue I see is that the server address should not be in a list, so like this:

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('sample', bootstrap_servers='0.0.0.0:9092')
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

No running cluster would also give that error. First create a topic:

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic sample
```

Then test if it exists:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
# sample
```

Lastly make sure there is a producer creating messages to listen to:

```py
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='0.0.0.0:9092')
producer.send('sample', b'Hello, World!')
producer.send('sample', key=b'message-two', value=b'This is Kafka-Python')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `api_version=(0, 10, 1)`option in your consumer definition:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    "USER_CREATED_TOPIC",
    bootstrap_servers=["xxx.xx.x.x:9092"],
    api_version=(0, 10, 1),
)
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```